# How do you extract scclust objects and append them to a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I have a list of a few thousand scclust  objects. I need to write a function to loop through the clusters and append the 0's and 1's from each scclust object to a different data frame. I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this. Here's a small example of what the cluster data looks like and what I would like the data frame output to be.

```
my_list$cluster1
0 1 0 0 0

my_list$cluster2
0 1 1 0 0

my_df
id cluster_number new_column
1  cluster1       0
2  cluster1       1
3  cluster1       0
4  cluster1       0
5  cluster1       0
6  cluster2       0
7  cluster2       1
8  cluster2       1
9  cluster2       0
10 cluster2       0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is not so much a question about scclust, and more one about reshaping and combining lists in general; so here is a solution considering the general case of a list:

```r
my_list <- list(cluster1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
                cluster2 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0))

my_df <- stack(my_list)[, c(2, 1)]
my_df
#>         ind values
#> 1  cluster1      0
#> 2  cluster1      1
#> 3  cluster1      0
#> 4  cluster1      0
#> 5  cluster1      0
#> 6  cluster2      0
#> 7  cluster2      1
#> 8  cluster2      1
#> 9  cluster2      0
#> 10 cluster2      0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>